# Calculate the date of the previous month and the date before previous month using current date (data flow, ADF)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a date column which is the first day of each month (eg, 2020-01-01), I want to calculate the date of the previous month (eg, 2019-12-01) and the date before the previous month (eg, 2019-11-01). In the expression builder, do we have any function to handle it? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [subMonths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#submonths) function, something like:

```
subMonths(toDate('2020-01-01'), 1)

subMonths(toDate('2020-01-01'), 2)
```